# @MapKeyJoinColumn showing as null in mapping table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and currently attempting to do a mapping with entity type for both key and value. I have a problem with persisting the key (`country_id`) in the mapping table as it keeps getting represented as `null` under the column name: `mapkey_country_id` even though I clearly used `@MapKeyJoinColumn` to specify the column name as `country_id`.

More context on the question:

It is a basic question where I have a `Continent` entity with `Map<Country, Capital>` attribute. So I have written the following code:

**Continent Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Continent {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long cont_id;
    
    private String continent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cname")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name ="country_id",nullable=false)
    private Map<Country, Capital> countries;

    //   followed by setters and getters...
}
```

**Capital Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Capital {

    private String capital;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long capital_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="cont_cap",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="capital_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="cont_id")
    )
    private Continent cname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;
    
    // followed by setters and getters...
}
```

**Country Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long country_id;

    private String country;

    //  followed by setters and getters...
}
```

**Main method**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sesfac = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    
    Session session= sesfac.openSession();
    
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    //country2
    Country country2= new Country();
    country2.setCountry("USA");
    
    Capital cap2= new Capital();
    cap2.setCapital("Washington, D.C.");
    cap2.setCountry(country2);
    
    Continent cont2= new Continent();
    cont2.setCname("North America");
    HashMap<Country, Capital> hm2 = new HashMap<Country, Capital>();
    hm2.put(country2, cap2);
    cont2.setCountries(hm2);
    cap2.setCname(cont2);
            
    session.save(country2);
    session.save(cap2);
    session.save(cont2);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the `@MapKey` annotation in this case instead of the `@MapKeyJoinColumn`:

```java
@Entity
public class Continent {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cname", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @MapKey(name ="country")
    private Map<Country, Capital> countries;

    // ...
}
```

As it explained in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-map-unidirectional):

> The `@MapKey` annotation is used to define the entity attribute used as a key of the `java.util.Map` in question.

Please note I added the `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}` to the `@OneToMany`. You can also correct your `Capital` entity in the following way:

```java
@Entity
public class Capital {

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;
    
    // followed by setters and getters...
}
```

and then persist operation will look like this:

```java
Country country = new Country();
country.setCountry("USA");
    
Capital capital = new Capital();
capital.setCapital("Washington, D.C.");
capital.setCountry(country);
    
Continent continent = new Continent();
continent.setCname("North America");
 
HashMap<Country, Capital> countries = new HashMap<Country, Capital>();
countries.put(country, capital);
continent.setCountries(countries);
capital.setCname(continent);

// It will save also Country and Capital due to the CascadeType.PERSIST usage
session.persist(continent);
```

Comment: Hi SternK, thanks for the reply, I tried using @MapKey and it works but it removes the mapkey_country_id entirely. is there a way to keep the map key column in the join table?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly do you want to do with `mapkey_country_id`. If you use bidirectional relationship as you have for the `Continent - Capital` , you can specify join columns only on one side of this relationship (usually on `@ManyToOne` side)

Comment: I thought it might be clearer to include all three relationships in the join table as this would create a centralised table for simpler reference. Is it uncommon to have a join table that includes the owner entity as well as the mapkey column and mapvalue column? Effectively, I hope to create a join table that has continent_id, country_id and capital_id.